# Operadores de Incremento e Decremento

Tags: c

Por que ele não somou o valor da variável 1 , com mais 1 na primeira printf.

```
int numero = 1;
printf("Conteudo armazenado na variavel: %d\n", numero++); /*(por que aqui da resultado 1? não estou pedindo para ele somar?)*/
printf("Conteudo armazenado na variavel: %d\n", numero++);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que procures a diferença entre ++x e x++ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094872/is-there-a-difference-between-x-and-x-in-java)

Ex:

x=1;

Com o x++ ele imprime o valor 1 e so no 2º print é que imprime 2

Caso seja ++x ele vai imprimir o 2, porque vai somar primeiro

Comment: , muito obrigado !!